# Firestore: Get subcollection of document found with where

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I am trying to get the documents inside an subcollection which is part of an document found with the .where function

Example:

- RootColl/
- Doc A/

  - SubColl 1

    - Doc 1
    - Doc 2
    - Doc 3
  - SubColl 2

    - Docs
- Doc A/

  - SubColl 1

    - Doc 1
    - Doc 2
    - Doc 3
  - SubColl 2

    - Docs

I want to get all the documents under `SubColl 1` from the doc with the field level == 1

I am trying to do it like:

```
db.collection("RootColl").where("field", "==", "1").collection("SubColl 1").get()
```

But by doing that I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: db.collection(...).where(...).collection is not a function

**EDIT 1:**
By following Frank van Puffelen suggestion, i get the same error, "collection" is not a function

- [Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtyNM.png)
- [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92MBB.png)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A sub-collection lives under a specific document. A query as you've shared now *points* to a number of documents. You'll need to execute the query to determine what documents it points to, then loop over the results, and get the sub-collection for each document.

In code:

```
var query = db.collection("RootColl").where("field", "==", "1");
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
    document.ref.collection("SubColl 1").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i get the same error:
`document.collection is not a function`

Comment: same `document.collection is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake. you'll need to get the `ref` from the `document` to get at the subcollection. I fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, are there any plans to write a guide or documentation how to work with subcollections on the web? The current documentation just states "subcollections are not supported on the web".

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple document in main collection and then sub collection, then use this code:

Data structure:
users(collection)-->>user1(doc)-->group(collection)-->data(doc)
users(collection)-->>user2(doc)-->group(collection)-->data(doc)

```
const mainRef = collection(db, "users"); //users is my main collection, containing all the users 
const users = await getDocs(mainRef); //Getting all the users
users.forEach(async (user) => { // loop through each user so that we got id for each document(user) to get sub collection data
  let userCollectionRef = collection(db, `users/${user.id}/groups`); //groups is my sub-collection name
  const GroupDoc = await getDocs(userCollectionRef); //getting all docs for particular user in sub-collection(groups)
  GroupDoc.forEach((item) => console.log(item.data())); // loop through each document in group for each user so that we got nested data 
});
```